# WP Query taxonomy.php to display posts from current term

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following `wp_query` within my `taxonomy.php` file to try and display the list of posts from within a term from that taxonomy.

I also have 6 taxonomies that I would like this to apply to, and so I would like to make the $args `'taxonomy' => 'topic'` and `'terms' => 'arabisation'` dynamic, to relate to the current page the user is viewing.

Thanks

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<section id="hero-image">
    <div class="gradient-overlay">
        <?php 
        // vars
        $queried_object = get_queried_object(); 
        $taxonomy = $queried_object->taxonomy;
        $term_id = $queried_object->term_id;
        $image = get_field('image', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id);

        // load image for this taxonomy term (term object)
        echo '<img src="'.$image['sizes']['large'].'" />';
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="grid">
        <header class="unit full-width">
            <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/" title="Kurdistan Memory Programme" class="logo"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
        </header>
        <footer class="unit one-half">
            <h1><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h1>
            <h4 class="scroll-down">Scroll down to continue</h4>
        </footer>
    </div>
</section>

<main class="grid">  
<? if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<? while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="unit col-6-12">
        <figure class="thumbnail">
            <? if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                  the_post_thumbnail();
            } ?>
            <figcaption>
                <h4><? the_title(); ?></h4>
                <h5><? the_excerpt(); ?></h5>
                <h6><a href="<? the_permalink(); ?>">View Project</a></h6>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
<? endwhile; ?>
<? endif; ?>   
</main>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Do not use a custom query

Comment: What do you mean by that @PieterGoosen? Can you help?

Comment: OK, will post an answer

Answer (score 0):

Taxonomy.php files already run a query that returns the posts with that taxonomy term applied, so try this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="unit col-6-12">
            <figure class="thumbnail">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                      the_post_thumbnail();
                } ?>
                <figcaption>
                    <h4><? the_title(); ?></h4>
                    <h5><? the_excerpt(); ?></h5>
                    <h6><a href="<? the_permalink(); ?>">View Project</a></h6>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The taxonomy.php file will auto-fill your loop, so you just need to use a standard wordpress loop to loop through all of your posts that match the chosen taxonomy term.

Comment: Hi @joe. Thanks for looking at this for me. Unfortunately that loop doesn't seem to be working. It is returning two posts, neither of which are in the current taxonomy term. One of which is actually a link to the same page I am currently viewing. I should be seeing 12 posts here, associated with this particular term?

The body tag contains the classes 'archive tax-topic term-arabisation' which are all correct.

Comment: Is there another loop on this page?

Comment: Actually, if you don't mind, could you post the full file's content? There could be something else causing the issue.

Comment: Have updated the code in the question temporarily for you. No second loop?

Comment: Check all of your "<?" tags. I could be mistaken, but doesn't each of those need to be "<?php" instead? I've never used just the bracket and question mark before. I've updated my code to reflect that change.

Comment: You are right that they should be <?php, but having changed them the output is still the same?

Comment: Looking over the code, I'm having a hard time spotting any errors. Are you certain that there's multiple posts assigned to this taxonomy term you are on?

Comment: Yes I am certain there are 12, but also, the 2 that are showing are from the wrong taxonomy?